# Why wont the child elements of the canvas move?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I have a canvas where there are various amounts of child elements on the canvas.  Im creating a drag and move feature but none of the children are moving.

```
if (blockClicked == false && canvasClicked == true)
{
     if (isDrag == true)
     {
         double deltaV = e.GetPosition(null).Y - pot.Y;   
         double deltaH = e.GetPosition(null).X - pot.X;

         double newTop = deltaV + (double)canv.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
         double newLeft = deltaH + (double)canv.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);

         Console.WriteLine("newTop: " + newTop);
         Console.WriteLine("newLeft: " + newLeft);

         this.canv.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newTop);
         this.canv.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newLeft);

         Console.WriteLine("canv new top: " + canv.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty));
         Console.WriteLine("canv new left: " + canv.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty));
    }
}
```

Above is the code i'm using, the outer if statement is just checking flags, but the inner IF statement is where i'm determining is the mouse being dragged. I get the Point of the mouse (pot) and then measure how much its moving and set the canvas value to that measurement.

However none of the children elements on the canvas move? can anyone explaint to me why this might be?

```
 <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    x:Name="canv" 
    ClipToBounds="False" 
    d:DesignHeight="0" d:DesignWidth="1180">

        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale"/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>

        <!--<Canvas x:Name="canv" Width="1000" Height="750" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">-->
        <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" 
               Width="1180" Height="784" Stretch="Fill"
               ClipToBounds="False">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="0.763909" RadiusY="0.611915" Center="0.496313,0.50023" GradientOrigin="0.496313,0.50023">
                    <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStop Color="#00456487" Offset="0.489691" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#B3456487" Offset="0.90404" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <TransformGroup />
                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
```

EDIT:
Above is the XAML included for the "canv" Canvas.

Peter

Comment: Do you want to show us a part of your XAML code?

Comment: What control/type holds this instance of the canvas?  Is it another parent canvas or is it a StackPanel/Grid?

Comment: It was a Grid, iv changed it now to a canvas, thanks Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, use this for getting the position:

> double deltaV = e.GetPosition(parentofcanvas).Y - pot.Y;
>            double deltaH = e.GetPosition(parentofcanvas).X - pot.X;

Secondly, use the Canvas.SetTop(..), Canvas.SetLeft(..), but if your Canvas isn't in a Canvas, you have to use its Margin property.

Comment: This is what I suspect is the issue; that the parent of `canv` is not a canvas but a `StackPanel`, `Grid`, or another panel that manages positioning/layout automatically.  In which case, as you say, `Margin` is the property to manage, not `Top` or `Left`.

Comment: My canvas wasn't within another canvas, it was contained in a Grid, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To set `Canvas.Top`, call `Canvas.SetTop(child, top)`, and similarly for `Left`.

Note that it is a static method - `Canvas.SetTop` and not `this.canv.SetTop`.

Comment: I thought there was no difference between `myCanvas.SetProperty(Canvas.Top, value)` and `Canvas.SetTop(myCanvas, value)` save for the compile-time value-type checking?

Comment: Don't pass a canvas into `SetTop`. Pass the child you want to set the property on.

Comment: You would pass it in if you wanted to move that canvas though, which is what Peter was trying to do.  `myCanvas` can just as easily be the "child" that you wish to move.  Unless you're suggesting that rather than moving the containing canvas, Peter should move all child entities within the canvas identical amounts?

Comment: I think he was moving the children of the canvas, since that is what was referred to in the question. If you are moving the canvas itself, then of course you need to move the canvas, and not child elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try my code: 
XAML - rectangle

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" MouseDown="rectangle1_MouseDown" MouseUp="Rectangle_MouseUp"
               Width="122" Height="78" Stretch="Fill"
               ClipToBounds="False" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="19">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="0.763909" RadiusY="0.611915" Center="0.496313,0.50023" GradientOrigin="0.496313,0.50023">
                        <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStop Color="#00456487" Offset="0.489691" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#B3456487" Offset="0.90404" />
                        </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            <TransformGroup />
                        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
```

C#:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
        dt.Start();
    }

    void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pressed == true)
        {
            Point c = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas1);
            Point c1 = Mouse.GetPosition(Rectangle);

            Canvas.SetLeft(Rectangle, c.X - c1.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(Rectangle, c.Y - c1.Y);
        }
    }
    bool pressed = false;
    private void rectangle1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    private void Rectangle_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        pressed = false;
    }
```